# Undesired results when populating an array from lodash fill vs regular array

Tags: javascript, arrays, multidimensional-array, lodash, fill

Question, is `_.fill(Array(4), [])` equal to `[[], [], [], []]`?

Because `_.isEqual(_.fill(Array(4), []), [[], [], [], []])` is `true`

```
var test = [[], [], [], []];
test[0].push(1);
console.log(test[0]);
test[1].push(2);
console.log(test[1]);
test[2].push(3);
console.log(test[2]);
test[3].push(4);
console.log(test[3]);
```

returns

```
[1]
[2]
[3]
[4]
```

which is I wanted, but

```
var test = _.fill(Array(4), []);
test[0].push(1);
console.log(test[0]);
test[1].push(2);
console.log(test[1]);
test[2].push(3);
console.log(test[2]);
test[3].push(4);
console.log(test[3]);
```

returns

```
[1]
[1, 2]
[1, 2, 3]
[1, 2, 3, 4]
```

Am I doing it wrong? I wanted to create and populate an array of arrays in which the `4` in `_.fill(Array(4), [])` is dynamic.

Answer (score 1):

`[]` is equivalent to `new Array()` in JS.

This means that `[[], [], [], []]` is an array with 4 new arrays, and `_.fill(Array(4), [])` is an array containing four copies of the same array.

In other words, the `_.fill` variant is equivalent to:

```
var a = [];
var test = [a, a, a, a];
```

---

If you want to make a multidimensional array, you can do:

```
_.map(Array(n), function () { return []; })
```

to create a 2-dimensional array.