# Array.fill gives same object repeated. why?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

```js
var arr = new Array(4).fill({});

arr[2].status = true;

console.log(arr[0].status);
```

why is array fill filling same object in all indexes?

Comment: Because you're inserting the same object to every cell within the array.

Comment: Go with `Array.from({length: 4}, () => {})` if you want a new object for each item.

Comment: _"why is array fill filling same object in all indexes"_ That's like asking "why does console.log('hello') log hello"_. I don't understand your confusion.

Comment: see [Changing one cell in multidimensional array updates entire column](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34118571/1048572)

Answer (score 14):

`.fill` will insert the same exact object (same instance) on each segment of the array.
That's why doing `.fill(Math.random)` will return an array filled with always the same number.

You can do this to obtain what you want:

```
new Array(4).fill().map(() => ({}));
```

To explain what's happening under the hood in your question's code, let's convert this to ES5 code:

```
var arr = new Array(4);  // new Array(4)
var obj = new Object();  // *1: with this object instance
for(i = 0; i < 4; i++) { // .fill( *1 )
  arr[i] = obj;
}
```

As you can see, we are assigning the same object instance (`obj`) to each cell of the array instance.

This is the same principle of why:

```
const obj = {};
const a = obj;
const b = obj;

a.foo = true;
```

Makes `a.foo === b.foo` resolve to `true`.

Comment: `fill` is also part of ES2015 not ES5

Comment: Yes, that is worked, +1. Please add the idea that the value is a object reference and every item is a reference.

Comment: I really like the "To explain what's happening under the hood..." Note: `var obj = new Object();` `{}` isn't new, no reason to use `new Object()` rather than `{}` in the ES5 version.

Comment: I think it's gives better the idea of "new instance being created"

Comment: This is correct! However, `fill()` complains of no argument provided, so you still need to fill it with the object you want, then eventually the map will still swap the new one for the duplicates.

Comment: @AbdulGafarOlamideAjao you must be referring to TypeScript, you can just pass it `undefined` to make it happy.

Comment: In Es6 you can use the spread operator to save some space: `[...Array(size)].map()`

Answer (score 11):

`fill` repeats the **value** you pass it. The value in this case is an object reference. Every copy of that reference refers to the same object, so what you're getting is:

```
       +−−−−−−−−−+
arr−−−>| (array) |
       +−−−−−−−−−+         +−−−−−−−−−−−−−−+
       | 0       |−−+−+−+−>|   (object)   |
       | 1       |−/ / /   +−−−−−−−−−−−−−−+
       | 2       |−−/ /    | status: true |
       | 3       |−−−/     +−−−−−−−−−−−−−−+
       +−−−−−−−−−+
```

If you want separate objects, you'll need to create multiple objects. The simplest way is, of course:

```
var arr = [{}, {}, {}, {}];
```

Example:

```js
var arr = [{}, {}, {}, {}];
arr[2].status = true;
console.log("arr[0].status", arr[0].status);
console.log("arr[2].status", arr[2].status);
```

**If** you want to do it with a variable length:

Since you're using `Array.fill`, I'm assuming you're using ES2015 (aka "ES6") features (but see below for an ES5-compatible solution without polyfills). You can do that via `Array.from` with a callback:

```js
const arr = Array.from({length:4}, () => ({})); 
arr[2].status = true;
console.log("arr[0].status", arr[0].status);
console.log("arr[2].status", arr[2].status);
```

That gives you:

```
                    
       +−−−−−−−−−+       
arr−−−>| (array) |       
       +−−−−−−−−−+         +−−−−−−−−−−−−−−+
       | 0       |−−−−−−−−>|   (object)   |
       | 1       |−−−−−+   +−−−−−−−−−−−−−−+
       | 2       |−−−+ |   
       | 3       |−+ | |   +−−−−−−−−−−−−−−+
       +−−−−−−−−−+ | | +−−>|   (object)   |
                   | |     +−−−−−−−−−−−−−−+
                   | |     
                   | |     +−−−−−−−−−−−−−−+
                   | +−−−−>|   (object)   |
                   |       +−−−−−−−−−−−−−−+
                   |       | status: true |
                   |       +−−−−−−−−−−−−−−+
                   |                      
                   |       +−−−−−−−−−−−−−−+
                   +−−−−−−>|   (object)   |
                            +−−−−−−−−−−−−−−+
```

(You can do that with an `Array.from` polyfill on ES5 if you like, just use `function() { return {}; }` instead of `() => ({})`.)

---

In ES5, if you need a variable length, the simplest thing is probably just a loop:

```js
var arr = [];
for (var i = 0; i < 4; ++i) {
    arr[i] = {};
}
arr[2].status = true;
console.log("arr[0].status", arr[0].status);
console.log("arr[2].status", arr[2].status);
```

You could put that in a helper function, of course.